# I Lost Fedora entry point

Tags: windows-8, grub, fedora-19

I had Windows 8 on my laptop and i installed Fedora 19 after that. I also installed grub-customizer on Fedora and I was being able to reach both operating system via GRUB screen on start-up.

Recently I had to format my C drive and reinstalled Windows 8. Now, my GRUB screen is gone and I don't know how to reach my Fedora.

I have to get my files on Fedora, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was it on UEFI? If so, it's easy. If not, will be a little more involved. First check if you are [running UEFI](http://blogs.technet.com/b/home_is_where_i_lay_my_head/archive/2012/10/02/how-to-check-in-windows-if-you-are-using-uefi.aspx). Another way of checking, open `diskmgmt.msc` and right click your drive box on the left, and see if you're using GPT. If so, you're definitely on UEFI.

UEFI: Add the option to fedora using [easyuefi](https://superuser.com/a/601485/203254) or, if you like command-line, `bcdedit`.

BIOS: If not, you'll have to boot up using a live disc, and repair your bootloader.

Alternative option: If you just need your files back, you can use [Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)

Comment: No, i didn't install on UEFI. I checked again to be sure, and my bios mode is legacy. I tried to use live disc but it acted like the first time installing fedora. It didn't see OS. I think i will use Linux Reader and install Fedora again.