# Windows 8 bootloader fails to start after installing Fedora 17

Tags: linux, windows-8, bootloader, efi

I installed Windows 8 (which was pre-installed) on my machine. Later, I installed Fedora 17, but the Windows loader must have been damaged. Then, I cannot see the Windows boot, I can only see GRUB.

I then downloaded the Windows 8 (evaluation copy) ISO image, and I started with this DVD. On the command line, I followed the solution proposed by [How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader) (so, I created a new boot CD). Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

I had to repair the GRUB, and surprisingly, a line for Windows 8 appears on my GRUB. But, when I try to boot Windows 8 (using GRUB), it returns:

> "Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or sofware change might be the cause.
>   ....
>   File: \Boot\BCD
>   Status: 0x000025
>   Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors."

I've tried repeating the procedure again.

Using the Windows console (after starting with the Windows 8 installation DVD, evaluation copy), I did:

```
- I mounted the EFI partition at B:.
$ cd /d b:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot 
$ del BCD
$ bootrec /fixboot
$ bootrec /scanos (it found my Windows installation)
$ bootrec /rebuilbcd (I added the entry for the Win installation)
$ bcdboot c:\windows /l en-gb /s b: /f ALL
```

...but the result is the same, when I try to start Windows 8, it shows:

> "Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or sofware change might be the cause. .... File: \Boot\BCD Status: 0x000025 Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors."

I think the problem comes from the re-partitioning of partition C:. After installing Windows 8, I created a new partition from C: (for installing Linux). The partition for Linux is a EXT4, obviously created when I installed Linux. Then, my Windows boot loader crashed.

Any clues?

Comment: Just use the Windows Repair Console.

Comment: So, did you repair it ? I want to know because I have this problem now ..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing

`Bootrec.exe
bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
c:
cd boot
attrib bcd -s -h -r
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bootrec /RebuildBcd
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot`
hope that fixes your problem

the reference is http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Windows-failed-to-start-Status-0xc000225-File-Boot-BCD/td-p/1300469