# Recover Windows EFI Boot Manager after Grub install

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub, uefi

I had Windows 8 installed, and tried to install Xubuntu in another HDD on my desktop. After installation, I could only boot into Xubuntu, and never got into the OS selection menu in GRUB. So I ran [**Boot Repair**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in order to fix the boot problems.

The boot process got fixed, now it does boot into GRUB, where I have two Windows entries, but none of them actually work, I get the error:

```
error: no such device: 1CA0-4000
error: file 'EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi' not found
```

I've tried to run the Windows 8 installation again, and chose *Automatic Repair*, but it was not able to correct the problem. So I guess the EFI files in the windows EFI boot partition of the 1st disk got deleted/chaged. How do I get them back/fix the windows bootloader?

I'm doing all of this with UEFI boot, both in the OS installed on the disks, and the installation media (booting from a USB flash drive).

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces.

Comment: Found the answer [here][1], following the instructions in @Alex answer.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader