# After installing ubuntu 19.04, Windows 10 doesn't boot anymore

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I've recently installed ubuntu 19.04 in dual boot with windows 10 (both in UEFI). GRUB recognizes windows, but when I choose the option "Windows Boot Manager" the windows logo and the loading animation appear only for a few seconds, then the computer reboots, bringing me back to grub selection menu. I tried many things, including sudo `update-grub` and using `boot-repair`, but none of them worked. Here is the log for boot-repair, if that helps: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/35q4kqtqZG/ (I also have a 2tb hard drive as a secondary drive for data, but I use only one 240gb ssd for the operating systems).

The windows partition is still accessible through the file manager in Ubuntu. I've also disabled secure boot.

Both partitions are GPT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/611053/recover-windows-efi-boot-manager-after-grub-install?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me with POP-OS. If you can, use a Windows installation via flash drive. At the installer screen, select the repair option on the bottom left. Navigate to the advanced repair options and select the command prompt. Then use "fix-boot" followed by "fix-mbr". That sorted me out. I hope it works for you too :)