# When booting my computer all I get is a black screen with a blinking underscore

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-14.04, system-recovery

My computer (laptop) has dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14 (14.10 I believe).

Yesterday everything was working fine. I was on Ubuntu and I wanted to move PlayOnLinux to another partition to have more space on my Linux partition so while checking my partitions' format and I found a partition that Linux categorized as "Free space". So I grabbed it and gave it Linux format. Later I remembered that when I created my Linux partition on windows a while ago, there was this free partition that, if I recall correctly, windows didn't let me change.

So everything was fine after that, more disk space. Then I turned off my computer and this morning I turned it on. The ASUS logo appeared and right after that, a white blinking underscore appeared on the top left of a black screen, no GRUB.

My guess is I must have messed up the computer when formatting that partition. Here are the things I've tried:

- F1-12: only F2 works (BIOS) and F4 (ASUS tek easy flash utility, with pretty much nothing on it)
- Hitting spacebar as if it were a F key (read it somewhere over the internet): nothing happened
- I've tried forcing boot from HDD from the BIOS but it goes back too the underscore screen.
- I placed a W.Vista recovery CD (because hell knows why I made a Vista recovery CD and not a w7 one) and it loads the recovery program correctly (I cancelled it, want to try if I can get w7 back).
- I can't find my Linux installation DVD so I haven't tried that.

Some computer info:
W7/Ubuntu 14 dual boot
ASUS K53SJ
iCore i5 (does that even help?)
A few years old

As with most laptops, no Windows 7 installation DVD came with it.

Comment: Might want to try http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ it has worked for me when I have done these types of things...

Comment: It worked! I was about to use EFI but since this seemed more simple I tried it, both Windows and Ubuntu are now bootable. I have one question: should I delete everything I put into that partition, should I not touch it or can I keep using it?

Comment: I'm not too sure.  When you are in Ubuntu your Windows partitions might look like empty space.  I would recommend leaving partitions alone unless you know exactly what is on them.  With a dual boot system it is a bit trickier because of the different file systems and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you have formatted your EFI boot partition, if your motherboard supports it.
On the [specification page for your Ultrabook](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K53SJ/specifications/) I cannot find any information on whether it uses EFI, but it's likely that it does.

You may wish to try the [rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as [suggested in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/613029/300646) (by the tool's own author), but if that does not work you must reinstall either Windows or Linux, to your preference.

If you can get hold of a Windows installation disk, you can browse the partitions to find out *exactly* what you did, but as mentioned earlier it's likely that you wiped the EFI boot partition.

Comment: The BIOS has a "Launch EFI Shell from filesystem device" which leads to a "Not found" warning message, so you're probably right. I will try this rEFInd Boot Manager and inform about the result.