# Unable to load Windows after using EasyBCD to Reset bcd

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, uefi, easybcd

My windows installation was working perfectly fine until i clicked **"Reset BCD"** in **EasyBCD** in Windows 8. After clicking that **EasyBCD** told me to add Win 8 entry via **Add Entry Menu** so i did. After restart, win 8 would not start. Neither would recovery F11.

#### Attempts i made to Restore :

1. Ran **boot-repair** from ubuntu live cd several time.
2. Used **Win8 system recovery disc** created via virtualbox with win 8 preview iso.
3. Automated repair from **Win8 system recovery disc**
4. Ran following commands from cmd started from **Win8 system recovery disc**

   > **bootrec /fixmbr** 
   >       Result : Success message 
   >       **bootrec /rebuildbcd** 
   >       Result : after hitting (Y) "The requested system device cannot be found"
5. **System refresh** started from **Win8 system recovery disc** gives error that **device is locked.**
6. **System reset** started from **Win8 system recovery disc** gives error that required partition or device is **missing or not accessible**.
7. Used **automated repair** from [EasyRE](https://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EasyRE/Automated+Repair) disc. It gave success message.
8. Used **Fix boot problem** from [Macrium reflect winPE repair disc](http://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50011.aspx).
9. Copied **Recovery** partition to usb. Booting from usb gave this error

   > Your PC needs to be repaired. 
   >   Error Code : 0XC000000f 
   >   Press **Enter** to **try again** 
   >   Press **F8** for **Startup Settings** 
   >   **F8 & Enter does nothing**
10. I cannot install WIn7 or Win 8, error it gives : 
    **"windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style."**

Comment: Can you describe what happens after POST? Does it give an error or anything?

Comment: I, too, pressed on reset within EasyBCD and ran into the same problem. The following answer solved my problem.
http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader

Answer (score 0):

You must boot in UEFI mode from the DVD. Look at the manual which key you have to press to get the boot menu shown. Here you should see BIOS and UEFO boot for DVD.

Comment: i can enter Boot menu by F10 but after turning off legacy mode i cannot use recovery disk as boot option. It will proceed to boot from hard disk option and throw "no bootable device found"