# Repairing Windows 8 EFI bootloader after installing Fedora 20

Tags: windows-8, bootloader, uefi

### Background

System is self built, so no OEM stuff. Windows 8 was installed first, hard drive was also newly set up as GPT. Later on, I installed Fedora 20 which installed GRUB on a BIOS Boot partition.

GRUB was loading Fedora fine but wasn't loading Windows properly so I've decided to scrap my Fedora installation and just set it up on a separate hard drive. After wiping my Linux partitions, I've done:

```
bootrec /fix
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /scanos # doesn't recognize any installation
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Which wiped out GRUB, but now I boot to a missing operating system error.

### Now

Current disk layout from gdisk:

```
Number Size        Code    Name
  1    300MiB      2700    Basic data partition # WinRE partition
  2    100MiB      EF00    EFI system partition
  3    128MiB      0C01    Microsoft reserved partition
  4    136.7GiB    0700    Basic data partition
```

The ESP contains:

```
/Boot/
  BCD
  BCD.LOG, BCD.LOG1...
  BOOTSTAT.DAT
  memtest.exe
  Localization, resource, and fonts folders
/EFI/
  Boot/
    bootx64.efi
  Microsoft/
    Boot/
      BCD
      BCD.LOG, BCD.LOG1...
      boot.stl
      bootmgfw.efi
      bootmgr.efi
      bootstat.dat
      memtest.efi
      Localization, resource, and fonts folders
/bootmgr
/BOOTNXT
```

bcdedit also reports:

```
Windows Boot Manager
identifier          {bootmgr}
device              partition=I:
path                \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
...

Windows Boot Loader
identifer           {default}
device              partition=C:
path                \Windows\system32\winload.efi
....
```

I've also tried following the directions [here](https://superuser.com/a/504360) but after rebooting it still gives a missing operating system error. (I've done the procedure both with and w/o secure boot)

rEFInd also does not detect any bootloader.

Is there any other way to repair the bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could have almost certainly fixed your initial problem by either installing Fedora 20 in EFI mode or installing the [EFI-mode Linux boot loader of your choice](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) on your computer. Of course, with Fedora wiped, that doesn't really do you much good; I mention it simply in the hope of helping you learn, or helping somebody else who might need that advice.

As to your problem, it sounds as if your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) has been damaged, but you haven't presented information on its contents. I'm also unfamiliar with the format of the Windows partitioning tool you've used. It shows a FAT32 partition (which is presumably the ESP), but it's unclear if it's marked with the correct type code. The ESP should be marked as such (with, for instance, a type code of EF00 in `gdisk` or a "boot flag" in `parted`), and the Windows boot loader file is `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. If that file is missing, that's the problem. I'm not an expert on the Windows repair tools, but the page to which you linked says to use `bootrec /fixboot`, whereas you used `bootrec /fixmbr`, among other differences. Assuming Microsoft hasn't simply reused an old name, I wouldn't expect `/fixmbr` to be useful on an EFI/GPT-booting computer, since EFI doesn't store boot code in the disk's MBR.

Comment: I ended up just reinstalling Fedora, only this time under EFI mode. Only thing to take note was that automated mountpoints wasn't recognizing the pre-existing ESP. Now I can dual boot properly.