# Windows 8.1 boot error

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, partitioning

I tried to install linux on a second partition of my hardrive, and now I can no longer boot into either system.

The error I get when booting is:

```
The Boot Configuration for your PC is missing or contains errors.
File: \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BCD
Error code: 0xc000000f
```

I have tried automatic repair, but that says it cannot fix the problem.

When i try to refresh PC, it says windows drive is locked

`bootrec /fixmbr` completes "successfully"

`bootrec /fixboot` completes "successfully"

`bootrec /rebuildbcd` finds my OS on "D:\Windows" and when I hit Y to add to boot list, it returns "the requested device cannot be found"

I have run chkdsk on D and C, both say they have fixed problems.

Diskpart list vol shows all volumes as "healthy" although there is nothing in "Info" field

Comment: So neither GRUB nor the Windows Bootloader is currently working?

Comment: Nope. 
trying to get GRUB working with boot-repair-disk and seems to be fixing, will update soon.

Comment: @Ramhound GRUB now loads, but only sees multiple versions of windows UEFI (all show the blue error page)

Comment: fixed using this:

http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader