# Windows 8.1 Pro won't boot, Status: 0xc000000e

Tags: windows-8, bcd, bcdedit, easybcd, bcdboot

My computer has been working fine until yesterday. I turned it on and immediately after the motherboard logo, I got an error screen (light blue) saying, `Your PC Needs to be Repaired` with an error code `Status: 0xc000000e`. There was no file/driver specified.

I have tried many different solutions such as this one: [Windows 8 EFI Boot Loader](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader) and trying to rebuild the BCD, etc. , but none of them has worked so far.

I am about to reinstall the entire OS, but wanted to ask here before I do that since I really feel there must be a solution for this.

The OS is installed on an SSD formatted as GPT with UEFI so it has three partitions:

1. Primary - 111GB
2. Recovery - 300MB
3. System - 100MB

I tried using `bcdedit /enum` to check the locations of the partitions and both the osdevice and device locations were showing up as "Partition=C:", but the {bootmgr} was showing up in the "partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3".

I am really struggling to figure out what's wrong. I disconnected all other drives and tried to "Startup Repair" the computer from the recovery DVD to no avail. It still throws up the "0xc000000e" error.

I tried the following:

• CHKDSK /R --> No Problems Found
• SFC /SCANNOW --> No Integrity Violations Found
• STARTUP REPAIR --> Ran about TEN times - couldn't repair

Please help!

Comment: I had the same problem with W7, try this : [0xc000000e Boot Error](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/0xc000000e-boot-error/ef08ab00-e130-4301-bc80-79d5b414a81f)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix booting for UEFI using this command:

**bcdboot c:\Windows /s Z: /f ALL**

c: is where Windows is installed

Z: is EFI System Partition (to map use "**mountvol Z: /s**" on command prompt)

[Some explanations for repairing Windows BCD](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html).

Comment: That was the only thing that helped! Thank you very much!