# Move Windows bootloader to another disk

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1, bootloader, system-reserved-partition

So i am planing on copying my C: drive to an SSD however my bootloader is on a secondary hard drive somehow. I have used the bootrec function with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful or not, but you can try to repair the Windows 8 EFI bootloader, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader). Firstly, you would have to CLONE the original harddisk, not just copy its files to the SSD; use a tool like CloneZilla (it's free). Eventually, if the bootlaoder cannot be fixed, you would have to locate the bootloader files on your secondary hard drive (google them up) and copy these to the same locations on the SSD - possibly you will have to create extra directories to do so. Hope this helps, good luck!