# Acer Aspire E1-430 - Operating System Not Found

Tags: windows-8, laptop, acer-aspire

I have a laptop Acer Aspire E1-430, but suddenly without me knowing what happened, an operating system not found occured that I can't use it anymore.

I've tried a solution from the net to have it in Legacy BIOS, yes it found the OS but the problem is with the display, it seems like that monitor is dying...

Do I really have to set it to Legacy BIOS for it to work again? What was happening? Why was it cannot find anymore the OS in the UEFI mode? And why in Legacy BIOS mode it distorted the display?

Can anyone give a better solution for this? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard that when the monitor displays `Operating system not found` the problem is with the monitor. When my monitor broke, the PC still booted with no problem.

I guess you managed to boot into Safe Mode, a mode where only basic drivers are loaded. This results in a wrong resolution and some displays look bad but there is no monitor problem.

About solving the problem:

- I understand you're using UEFI with GPT
- disable Legacy BIOS or CSM or whatever
- get a bootable Windows installation media (DVD or USB)
- boot in UEFI mode from it
- choose `Repair my computer` when the welcome screen appears and you are prompted to install Windows
- open a Command Prompt
- run `bootrec /fixboot`
- restart

This may not correctly detect EFI system partition, so if it doesn't work, see [this](https://superuser.com/q/460762/334004).

Comment: But the problem is it won't detect any of my device if I switch back to UEFI. So, I can't make it boot to any installation media (DVD or USB) when I'm in UEFI mode. That's why I was confused, because it's in UEFI mode before it happened "Operating System not found". So I switched to Legacy BIOS where it boot up but monitor display is somewhat blurred and seems like about to die... but I don't believe it's a monitor problem.