# Kali Linux and windows 8 issue

Tags: linux

ok so I download Kali Linux to a usb stick plug it into my computer and I had to change my EFI to legacy I did everything went smoothly until I wanted to get back to windows 8 I restart my computer go into my boot options and windows boot is gone. So I don't have windows 8 someone plz help.

Comment: What do you mean Windows boot is gone? Is the entry gone or the bootloader gone (replaced by GRUB)?

Answer (score 0):

First, put it back in EFI mode and then try to boot. If it doesn't work: This is a known problem with EFI and kali linux. [How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader)

Comment: Duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader