# Is installing a different distro over ubuntu on a dualboot system possible? Or deleting partition necessarily?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I run a dualboot with ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1. I messed up the ubuntu and now I'm going to install elementary OS instead of ubuntu. I wounder how I should do it in the easiest way possible without mess upp something. Should I first just delete the partition where I have ubuntu on and then create a new partition in windows and on that new partition install elementary OS?

Or can I install elementary distro over the current ubuntu distro and that partition with ubuntu will be overwritten with the installation of elementary OS? So the partition will be like a clean partition with just elementary on it instead of ubuntu? I mean this would be possible if I were to reinstall ubuntu right? So is it possible when I choose to install another distro?

If I had to remove the partition at first will that give some problem to start windows then? I mean I know have a "bootmeny" in grub where I can choose either windows or ubuntu from. But windows have it's own so that problem shouldn't occour? Is there anything else that can go wrong if I remove the partition with ubuntu on?

//UPDATE//

I booted Elementary OS and run the alternative delete ubuntu and install Elementary. The install failed. It said it couldn't install a grub file. Tried to restart the computer but it didn't work to shut down, restart or log off so I were forced to a power button shutdown. When I restart I get like a terminal with GRUV> and then you can write commands wich are listed on the screen when you tab but I don't now what to write?

It is possible to boot into windows pressing F1/F12 and accesing windows boot.

I see three choices: 
1.delete the linux mess partitions, but I don't now what partitions windows 8.1 and my computer use by default? How can I figure that out?

2.write some command in grub for something I don't know.

3.find another distro and install that ontop of a messed ubuntu and a messed elementary os.

My laptop is an Lenovo g510 i7 4700MQ with preinstalled windows 8.
Sugestions?

//UPDATE2//
How do I completely remove grub? I decided to go with linux mint instead but when i choose to boot from the usb with linux mint done with unetbootin. I don't have a choice to install it I can just test it. And when I get to the advanced startup I can choose to boot from usb, cd and so on and I also have an alternative called Ubuntu? What? So I guess remove grub atached to some minimal ubuntu garbage left over will be the call?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Paragraph 2 - install overtop of Ubuntu partition should work. Don't need to remove the partition, but erasing files or reformatting couldn't hurt, I don't know if every distro will erase old files or try to use some.

May need to [repair your windows bootloader](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader) if it's gone after deleting Ubuntu & decide not to install another linux.

-> After reading updated info, I thought since you had Ubuntu installed before then installing another one would be ok. I'm not sure what to think about Elementary OS, it's screenshots look nice but apparently it couldn't install itself? You may find help in this post "[Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)".

Or maybe the problem is: It sounds like you've got multiple hard drives with a changing boot order, if pressing "F1/F12" gets to a boot menu of some sort you may be choosing the windows drive to boot from successfully, or at least the drive with a good boot menu... but booting from a different drive each time would mix things up.

Or if it's just grub, a tool like [Boot Repair might help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to configure grub... it is theoretically possible to use grub from the "`GRUB>`" prompt, but I wouldn't try it without a few pages of instructions on another computer next to me.

Comment: I tried an overtop installation but didn't went well. Se my first post for information.

Comment: I have only one hard drive. But with different partitions. I think a solution might be to get rid of grub so i tried:http://askubuntu.com/questions/489929/delete-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-windows-8-1-in-gpt-disk  but it didn't work. Or can i delete grub with Boot Repair? Or how do I get rid of grub?

Comment: That's what I was hoping the "repair your windows bootloader" link I posted would do, that askubuntu question looks friendlier/easier though

Comment: I managed to install linux mint and after the installation of the OS was done then grub changed like I wanted to. So get rid of grub didn't work but no problem with overinstall it like the OS did do I guess? That solved my problem, thx Xen2050 for your time

Comment: You're welcome. The last OS to install often writes it's own bootloader, overwriting whatever used to be there. Linux like Ubuntu & Mint *should* make a boot entry for any existing OS's, but Windows will often overwrite with it's own, ignoring any Linux. Mint does have the "Install Linux Mint" on the Desktop/Start menu after it boots "live", I run it from a multiboot USB with a different boot menu (just copy iso file & edit a grub config file using linux - instructions here (using ext3 instead of FAT32 for me) http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/