# Grub does not find windows10

Tags: linux, boot, grub, manjaro, dualboot

so yesterday I changed from Linux Mint to Manjaro with Gnome and wanted to just remake my grub config. Sadly grub does not find my Windows Boot.

Output from lsblk:

```
sdb                                                                         
├─sdb1
│    ntfs         SystemReserved
│                       01D50D5FDB172900                                    
├─sdb2
│    ntfs         SYSTEM
│                       01D50D78773A8C60                                    
└─sdb3
     ntfs               01D50D7891E5C9D0
```

Edit: os-prober is also installed, but yields no results!

Can you guys help me (Grub worked before with Mint and Windows DualBoot)

Comment: Try this Super User page there are a few pages here. Look at Related to the right.  https://superuser.com/questions/900804/windows-8-1-fails-to-boot-after-linux-mint-17-1-install?rq=1

Comment: So far there was nothing that would have helped me sadly.

Comment: Have you tried booting a Windows disk to get to a Command Prompt? Is it UEFI or other? Windows Command Prompt __bcdboot C:\Windows__ where C:\Windows is your partition for Windows.

Comment: How do  I distinguish between UEFI and other here?

Comment: Which ever is the largest hard disk partition I would imagine. You might want to use Microsoft's __Diskpart__. At at Windows Command prompt type "Diskpart" it will open with a prompt. Type __select disk 0__ then type _List partition_ that might tell you which partitions Windows is on. If It does not, type __List volume__  it __should__ be the 2nd partition on the hard drive, List Volume should give you a drive letter also, if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount your Windows Partition first!

If this is not working try to install `ntfs-3g` with `sudo pacman -S ntfs-3g` and remount your Windows partition.

Then try `sudo update-grub`

ref: arch wiki][1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#MS_Windows)

Comment: Hi, so my windows partition (all of them exactly) were mounted at the time.
Gonna try the ntfs3g though tonight!

Comment: So sadly this did also not do the trick, osprober does still not find it :/