# Windows 8 "chkdsk /r" stuck on stage 4

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, chkdsk

I know that there are many questions about this topic but I think my situation is a bit different and since I'm a newbie, I'd need some tips and help specific for my case.

I have a Windows 8 pc which was not starting anymore. It's an Asus SonicMaster. At BIOS runtime it says that Windows is not able to start and I tried some of the advanced options:

1 - Recovering it for a restore point: it says that it is unable to do that;
2 - Updating it: it says the it can't do that since the disk is locked (I actually have no idea about that);
3 - Maybe I have done some other trials I don't remember now, but basically nothing worked for me.

Then I found a tutorial online suggesting to run `chkdsk /r`. Thus, in the advanced options I chose the command line prompt and I run it on the C: disk. The result is that now it has been stuck for more than 12 hours on stage 4. At the beginning it was stuck on 14 percent but the number of files processed was growing up. But after few minutes the number of file got stuck too and now it has been stuck on 179408 for more than 12 hours.

I read over the Internet that stopping chkdsk is highly unsafe, but basically I don't know what to do right now. Can anybody help me?

As a side question, the command line showed me to be in the X: partition, where from the fs tree structure seems to be installed a Windows with no users... Actually the real boot partition is C, where the user is present... Do you think this may be the root of the issue that I am not able anymore to start Windows? If so, I tried to change the boot partition from the Boot Menu, but it's not feasible since the only option there is "Windows Boot". How can I change the boot partition?

*** UPDATE ***

Due to a power down, the pc shut down. Then, when I booted it again, nothing seemed to be changed. Thus, I followed this tutorial: [How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader) and now I'm lost!

Now it comes out a blue screen with the error message:

```
File: C:\Windows\system32\config\system
Error code: 0xc0000185
```

Pressing F8 to get the boot option doesn't work, since it comes back to this page. What can I do?

Thank you very much,
Marco

Comment: If you boot with non-standard Windows boot options (like the Recovery options), it may map drives differently.  So the idea that your normal partition is re-mapped to X: is not alarming.  Another note: I edited the question because I'm pretty sure that chkdsk expects forward slashes.

Comment: Interrupting a Chkdsk (that makes changes) can cause problems; if it partially updates a "table" (visually think of this as a "chart"), you may end up w/ details that don't match each other.  On the other hand, if Chkdsk's attempts to repair stuff is unsuccessful, it may keep trying to perform more and more actions as it tries to make sense of some details, and this may result in continuing to make more changes and making a bigger mess of things.  Sadly, often there may not be an easy way to be certain (ahead of time, or during the attempt) if letting it go is actually doing more good or harm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Meanwhile, unfortunately there was a power down in my home, thus the pc shut down. I was frightened by that, but when it started up it looked like before. Now I'm facing another issue, I'm updating the question. May you answer to my new issue? Thanks.

Comment: This is not the proper way to use SuperUser.  Your original question here is specific to Chkdsk.  If my answer was correct or useful, mark it accepted.  Otherwise, don't.  (I'm fine either way.)  But please don't ask a new unrelated question, even though this cropped up during your same experience.  Instead, make a new question about the BSOD.  (You may want to add a hyperlink, referencing this question, as some background information on what likely led to the error.  And make your question about what to do next for troubleshooting.)

Comment: Info has been [copied](http://superuser.com/questions/1043297/windows-boot-error-c-windows-system32-config-system-error-code-0xc0000185) when it should have been moved.  Anyway, info about the "update" is being answered with the new question.