# Windows boot error: C:\Windows\system32\config\system Error code: 0xc0000185

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

I experienced some issue with the Windows 8 boot phase and I tried to solve them ( you can find [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1043251/windows-8-chkdsk-r-stuck-on-stage-4) an explanation of what I did).

Now, the problem I have is that I followed the procedure in this tutorial: [How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader) and now the result is the following.

Now it comes out a blue screen with the error message:

```
File: C:\Windows\system32\config\system
Error code: 0xc0000185
```

Pressing F8 to get the boot option doesn't work, since it comes back to this page. What can I do?

Thank you, Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\Windows\system32\config\system` is a registry database file. This blue screen can occur if, for some reason, this has become corrupted.

One method you can use to recover from this is to boot into some form of boot disk, whether this is a Windows bootable setup (using command prompt from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) or a linux boot disk.

From here, you can make a copy of `C:\Windows\System32\config\system` as something like `C:\Windows\System32\config\system.old`. Within the folder structure `C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack` you will find last working backups of your registry.

You can copy the file from `C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\system` to `C:\Windows\System32\config\system`, which, if the issue is a corruption in this file, should get you back up and running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I am not able to boot from my USB (I have a linux live on it). The PC is a ASUS SonicMaster and has UEFI as a boot system. I don't know it actually, but in the boot menu I can't find anything but a Windows boot entry...thus I'm unable to run my live Linux..have you any idea about how to deal with it? Thank you.

Comment: @mark91 You may need to change your boot preference to `Legacy Mode` or similar temporarily to boot a non-EFI live system. There should be an option in your UEFI somewhere to change this.

Comment: I have been able to change the settings to `Legacy mode`, but I still can't boot from my USB. In the boot menu I can see only three options: the Windows boot which is the corrupted one, one which is called P2 DVDROM (I think is the DVD reader) and the Realtek interface... but there is no option for booting from a USB. Have you any idea? Thank you

Comment: @mark91 It's possible USB is disabled from boot somehow. You might have a BIOS option for something along the lines of USB emulation. It could also be a `fast boot` option, which means it may not be enumerating USB devices.

Comment: Actually it was not showing it to me when I put a live linux distribution. Now I put a Windows bootable USB (created as shown here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x) and the USB came out but it is not launching it: it skips the USB and goes to the second boot option... I guess I have to follow some special procedure to create a Linux live bootable USB for UEFI even if it is in legacy mode... I am googling a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Quick research indicates this error is caused by a failure to find files, which might be because of an error communicating with the hard drive, or missing files.  Given the known [history](http://superuser.com/questions/1043251/windows-8-chkdsk-r-stuck-on-stage-4), it seems likely that the issue is just that some files cannot be read.

This probably means that your filesystem volume (a.k.a. partition, C:) is corrupt.  I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news (and I recall people downvoting me the last time I did this), but that is my honest opinion of the current situation.

Before making any further changes, back up what you can.  If there are important files that are not backed up, try to copy them (or recover them using something like [TestDisk](http://cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)).  A safer/wiser/harder/more-time-consuming approach is to create an image of the entire hard drive, which can then be useful for being able to make multiple safer rescue attempts of any desired data.

At this point, I would not trust the filesystem volume for storing data until the filesystem volume has been successfully repaired by repair software like chkdsk.  Such repair might not be accomplishable, and so your only recourse may be to re-create the filesystem volume, which will delete all data.  However, once that is done, the new filesystem volume would then be expected to be reasonably reliable (as long as there are no hardware issues).

If you can get a filesystem volume repair program (like Chkdsk) does say that the filesystem volume is okay, that probably means that free space is trustworthy, and that some (and possibly all, but not necessarily all) pre-existing data is not corrupted.  If the data is really important and you're seriously concerned about its integrity, you may need to restore from backup or re-install/re-create data.

Until you get the filesystem volume repair program, there is a very high chance that an operating system will see some file entries, so it will look like the files exist.  Interacting with some files might even be possible, and so you may be able to copy the files.  However, interacting with (some) other files may not be possible.  (Attempting to read the bits belonging to the file may cause an issue, as some of the bits may not be properly locate-able.)  Also, the system's records of available free space may not be reliable, so writing to free space is not recommended.  (Doing so might cause further corruption of some data that would otherwise by retrievable.)  Even if quite a bit of data seems okay, I just wouldn't trust the filesystem volume until a completed process of repairing or re-creating the filesystem volume.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Given that I have a backup of all files, what should I do to have the system up and running? Should I re-install it?