# Physical to Virtual Migration using Disk2vhd utility

Tags: hard-drive, hyper-v, database-administration, data-migration

We are currently in plan of migrating physical to virtual servers for both DB & App servers. Currently we are with SQL Server 2014 AOAG System. Databases are FileStream enabled. Currently we have Data drive with 600GB , Log Drive with 400GB , FileStream drive with 6 TB.

As I am with AOAG , Can I use below method for all 3 AG Replicas. Kindly help.

Can I use Disk2vhd and create .vhdx for above Data ,Log and FileStream drives and create Hyper-V machines . Any one who has expertise on this metjod , can help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

disk2vhd has slow performance and no automation. Sometimes the converted VMs (especially Gen2) cannot boot until boot sector will be repaired. Here are some links with issues and discussions:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1810357-disk2vhd-physical-to-virtual-vhd-wont-boot

[DiskToVhd generated VHD is not bootable](https://superuser.com/questions/1070984/disktovhd-generated-vhd-is-not-bootable)

I used to test a couple P2V convertors (disk2vhd, starwind v2v, 5 nine v2v) during infrastructure virtualization. The most stable and feature-rich is starwind v2v - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter It automatically creates VM inside remote Hyper-V and fixes boot.