# Cannot boot on a Win10 SSD if Win7 SSD is not connected

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, bios

Long time ago, I had a Windows 7 installation on a 128Gb SSD.

I then upgraded to Windows 10 on a brand new 256Gb SSD.

I kept it as this for a while, but now I need my SATA socket to connect a new HDD.

But if I disconnect my Win7 SSD, the computer won't boot : I get to the UEFI BIOS screen, then I have either a black screen with the white cursor blinking, or the message telling me to insert a bootable drive. This happen if I don't touch the BIOS, but also if I select manually the win10 SSD.

Then, whenever I connect my win7 SSD, the computer will boot normally, whether I connect it by SATA or by USB 3.0 with an external box (which is totally weird to me).

In the BIOS, the boot order is : Win10 SSD only (the Win7 is not even mentionned)

In the partition manager, there are :

- Disk 1 : Win10 (healthy: exchange file, empty if trouble, main partition) and Unnamed (healthy: recuperation partition)
- Disk 2 : System reserved (healthy: System, active, main partition) ans Win7 (healthy: main partition)

How can I get rid of my win 7 SSD ?
(If you can explain what's going on this would be very interesting !)

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to reinstall, as found in an answer to [System Reserved partition on wrong drive - how do I move it?](https://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/189387-system-reserved-partition-wrong-drive-how-do-i-move.html#post1597904).

> 1) Open a command prompt as admin, then type the following:
>
> bcdboot C:\windows /s C:
>
> Hit Enter.
>
> This command places boot files on the C: partition which is your
>   windows.
>
> 2) Now open disk management, right click C: and click Mark active.
>   Right click System reserved and click Mark Inactive (unless its
>   already showing inactive).

I couldn't mark the System reserved partition inactive (there was no option to), but it worked anyway.