# Trying to repair Windows 10 bootloader

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, partitioning, bootloader

I'm having a nearly identical issue to the one described in [this](https://superuser.com/a/518184/527075) post. I'd expect the solution would work perfectly, however, I can't create the efi partition on the drive with Windows installed as the Windows drive is formatted with MBR. I get the following error:

```
MSR and EFI partitions are only supported on GPT disks.
Convert the selected disk to GPT and try again.
```

I don't want to lose any of my data so I tried plugging the drive into another PC and using easeus to convert to GPT but it failed.

Any ideas of how I can move forward with this?

Comment: If you have a spare hard-drive you could try copying the partition contents over, re-formatting the disk as gpt, then restoring the partitions

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you can approach this.

The most stable approach to this would be to find a spare Hard-Drive of adequate size, plug both drives into another machine and use a Partition Manager tool, like Paragon, to copy the partition contents to the new drive. Once you've backed up the partition contents you can safely re-format the old disk to a GPT disk, then restore the partitions to the GPT Disk.

You can also run AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro on another PC, and use that to convert to GPT. This shouldn't cause any Data Loss, however this isn't guaranteed.

I hope that you manage to get this resolved.