# Windows 8 EFI boot issue

Tags: windows-8, ssd, bootloader, efi

I've got a simular problem as described in [How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader), but with some different details.

When I tried to change the bootsequence of my harddisks (of which 1 SSD) in the BIOS (system=Medion Akoya P5306 F), I got the following error when I tried booting from the (previously perfect booting) SSD:

> Your PC needs to be repaired
>   The boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors
>   File: \EFI\Microsoft\BCD
>   Error code: 0xc000000f

When I booted from the other HDD, the SSD is visible in the Windows Explorer, but unaccessible. Auto repair using the Win8 support disk is also unable to fix the problem.

Using [this link](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2012/04/17/boot-bcd-0xc000000f-windows-7/) link, I tried

> bootsect /nt60 ALL /mbr
>   bcdboot c:\windows

Went ok, but no solution, since now the message was:

> Your PC needs to be repaired
>   The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
>   File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
>   Error code: 0xc000000f

Again, auto repair is unable to fix the problem.
Then I tried the solutions provided in [BootMgr is missing, usual fixes don't work](https://superuser.com/questions/358651/bootmgr-is-missing-usual-fixes-dont-work).

> bootrec /fixmbr
>   The operation completed successfully.
>   
>   bootrec /fixboot
>   The operation completed successfully.
>   
>   bootrec /scanos
>   Scanning all disks for Windows installations.
>   Please wait, since this may take a while...
>   Successfully scanned Windows installations.
>   Total identified Windows installations: 0
>   The operation completed successfully.
>   
>   bootrec /rebuildbcd
>   Scanning all disks for Windows installations.
>   Please wait, since this may take a while...
>   Successfully scanned Windows installations.
>   Total identified Windows installations: 0
>   The operation completed successfully.

So, no Windows installation is found...
Then I tried something myself, given the error message: I copied X:\Windows\System32\winload.efi to C:\Windows\System32
This seemed to have some effect, because now the message was:

> Your PC needs to be repaired
>   The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because the HAL is missing or contains errors.
>   File: \Windows\system32\hal.dll
>   Error code: 0xc000000f

So, I copied X:\Windows\System32\hal.dll to C:\Windows\System32, but now it's complaining about a missing Cl.dll. Since I'm not sure what I'm doing (duh...) I stopped this manual copying.

Also tried

> sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows
>   Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

...without luck.

I then tried some of the proposals from [this link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm):

> bcdedit /export c:\bcdbackup
>   The operation completed successfully.
>   
>   ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
>   
>   bootrec /rebuildbcd

Still no Windows installations. And although the bootrec indicated success, no C:\boot\BCD file was created!

So finally I ended up at [How can I repair the Windows 8 EFI Bootloader?](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader)

I assigned B: to the FAT32 partition:

> diskpart
>   select vol 3
>   assign letter=b:
>   list volume
>   Volume ####  Ltr  Label    Fs     Type       Size     Status   Info
>   -----------  ---  -------  -----  ---------  -------  -------  ------
>   Volume 0     E    Win8     UDF    DVD-ROM    4314 MB  Healthy
>   Volume 1     D             NTFS   Partition  167 GB   Healthy
>   Volume 2          Herstel  NTFS   Partition  300 MB   Healthy  Hidden
>   Volume 3     B             FAT32  Partition  99 MB    Healthy  Hidden

B: contains EFI\Microsoft\Boot (as does C:)
And this is the location where the BCD file got rebuild, given the timestamp.

> bcdboot c:\Windows /l nl-NL /s b: /f ALL

(nl-NL: yes, I'm Dutch)
Still, no solution. At startup it keeps complaining about the missing Cl.dll.

I'm running out of options and ideas. And I got stuck trying to understand the "Windows and GPT FAQ"

So, who has any bright ideas?
Also, any ideas to just access the SSD and backup the data would be fine!
If I access the C:\Users directory from the Win8 support disk command prompt, I only see my own account (because that's the only admin account?) and no documents in it for example.

Answer (score 4):

Try not using the "All" part of selecting the firmware in BCDBoot. Had the same problem, but selected just UEFI (my machine has it) and it worked! If you have BIOS just use

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /l nl-NL /s b: /f BIOS
```

Or for UEFI use

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /l nl-NL /s b: /f UEFI
```

Tell me how that goes.

Answer (score 2):

I boot Win8 from USBflash trying repair with most other answers with no result.
What helped for me was:

`bcdboot d:\Windows /l ru-ru /s c: /f UEFI`

I'll  mention this happened on ASUS n76vj on 256Gb SSD factory split on 5 partitions