# Windows 8.1 will not boot (HP Stream)

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, uefi

When I power on the laptop I'm greeted with a blue screen that reads, among other things:

```
The operating system couldn't be loaded because the HAL is missing or 
contains errors
```

Thankfully I can boot from a USB recovery drive, and have attempted several different fixes from those suggested in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader">) to rebuilding the BCD file from scratch as described [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/). All that changed were the startup errors, which varied from an issue with `\Windows\System32\winloader.exe` to exhibiting a completely black screen.

I would love to use something as simple as

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s B: /f ALL
```

to fix things, but this fails with some error in comparing checksums.

I'm not sure, but I get the feeling that if someone posted the results of

```
bcdedit /enum
```

from a working BCD file with the same laptop (HP Stream 13), I could make my own match it and be set. I do not know though. Any suggestions aside from wiping the thing with a clean install? If it's any help, I also have a bootable Linux USB that could be used in the repair process. Many thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I very much suspect that you have serious disk errors that are causing this. I don't think that anything will recover it though I could easily be wrong. I suggest doing some low-level checks on the disk. Also booting from a Linux livecd to look at data on the disk to see if it is corrupted.

Comment: Running `chkdsk` found no problems, is there some further/more thorough test I could run?

Comment: Smart test maybe?

Comment: Is that available from the command line?

Comment: It seems everything's okay with the drive, I just need to tell the computer how to load it is at startup. Somehow.

Comment: There should be a hard drive test from the bios, I suggest you run the extended version and see if it finds any bad sectors.

Comment: There might be an answer at http://superuser.com/questions/566935/windows-8-efi-boot-issue for a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions but I've decided a clean install will be the quickest solution (@DrM switching the `/f` flag had no effect I'm afraid).

Comment: Any constructive criticism from the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, one *cannot* remove the recovery partition from an HP Stream laptop as it uses a new OS layout called [WIMBoot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn594399.aspx). In brief, the recovery partition contains essential compressed `.wim` files that Windows loads as needed during normal operation. Thus deleting the recovery drive thoroughly breaks your OS.

I had wondered why, after copying the recovery partition to a USB drive I wasn't presented a `Delete the recovery partition` option as others were. It seems there was quite a good reason for it after all.

All this to say, **the only solution is to reinstall from the recovery media.** Unsurprisingly, this also recreates the recovery partition you had tried so hard to be rid of.

Comment: You do **can** remove the recovery partition and you do **not** need to reinstall from recovery media. You **do** however need to know what you're doing before you go about deleting your boot files.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Do tell. Did you read the link about WIMBoot?

Comment: Just found this out myself the hard way!