# How to repair encrypted Windows partition in external harddrive?

Tags: windows-7, boot, truecrypt, bootsector

I have a Windows 7 Professional on TrueCrypt encrypted hardrive (two partitons, encrypted as the whole drive).

The latest Windows update failed and afterwards the Windows didn't boot (blue screen of death during loading Windows). Safe boot didn't boot either so I booted up into the Windows repair console (from the encrypted HDD) and inadvertently issued `bootrec /fixboot`.

After restart the TrueCrypt boot screen wasn't there (fixboot replaced TrueCrypt MBR) but I was able to fix this with the TruCrypt Recovery Disk.

So now I have a TrueCrypt MBR fixed, but the Windows boot sector on C:\ is still bad. I can authenticate in TrueCrypt, but when it should load the OS, it says: Boot partition is missing.

With this advice: [Windows 7 startup repair with Truecrypt](https://superuser.com/questions/612509/windows-7-startup-repair-with-truecrypt)
I was able to mount the harddisk on another computer and with `TrueCrypt -> System -> Mount without Pre-Boot Authentication` I'm able to access the data on harddrive from another computer.

- Is there any option to fix the C:\ partition boot sector when connected as external harddrive?
- If so, what then when I will have an encrypted system that will load Windows, but crash during startup?