# SSD with OS doesn't work because HDD with bootloader is dead

Tags: hard-drive, bootloader, mbr, ssd

There was a common HDD with an old Windows 7 installation. A new SSD was bought, a new fresh Windows 7 was installed on it as a dual boot with the old HDD system.

Now, I could see that the new SSD OS needs the bootloader on the old HDD, but never thought it would actually not work without the HDD.

The HDD broke, now the OS on the SSD doesn't boot. "BOOTMGR is missing"

I tried loading from a bootable USB flash with command prompt, the SSD is visible, the rebuild of the `bootrec /rebuildbcd` was successful.

Still the SSD OS doesn't load. It says `no OS found`.

Comment: Do anyone of these solutions help: http://superuser.com/questions/358651/bootmgr-is-missing-usual-fixes-dont-work

Comment: I just solved the problem by simply auto-repairing the Windows 7 OS on SDD with the bootable USB flash drive.

Comment: Just for the recorcd: The SSD actually work worked fine.  It missed some software, but saying that it does not work is like saying "My paper notebook does not work because I have not yet written my notes on it".

Answer (score 3):

Actually all your system files are safe in your SSD.But you are missing a small piece of software , bootloader, which is a computer program that loads the main operating system or runtime environment for the computer after completion of the self-tests.

you can rewrite the bootloader to your MBR(in SSD) using the following methods.

1)Try Using the Automated Startup Repair from the Windows Install Disc.

[image]

2)
else you can get to the Command Prompt.[image]

type

> bootsect /nt60 all.

consider reading  [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) article