# Windows 7 won't boot (encrypted with Truecrypt 7.1a)

Tags: windows-7, boot, encryption, truecrypt

How the problem occured:
My laptop randomly shut's down (probably overheated).
After the last shutdown it could not boot windows anymore 
I could choose to use startuprepair or start windows normally

What i tried:
I tried to use Windows Startup Repair which couldn't solve it.
I viewed the detail post of it and everything went succesfull without the last part. the errorcod was something like "boot??? 0x490"

So i googled that errorcode and followed these step's on this site:
http://tipsandtricksforum.com/thread-201.html?PageSpeed=noscript

Now i can't even choose startuprepaird or start windows normally.
I think i damaged the boot section with these commands, since it's encrypted with Truecrypt.

Can i revert this commands? If not can i still save my files?

Comment: when i use the Rescued CD of windows it show's that it couldnt detect which OS and directory i use

Comment: The exact error code would be extremely helpful.  If the boot sector is damaged, not a great can be done, with a Truecrypt recovery disk which based on what you did, you probably do not have.

Comment: I'm 80% sure the errorcode was boot sector 0x490 ... my entire HDD is encrypted. i got the truecrypt rescue disk. which options should i choose?

Comment: IME:  Encryption + corruption (random shutdown) + corruption (user messing with boot data) = DATA GONE.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 are you sure?
What if i get a live cd and install truecrypt on this live cd?
Couldn't i try to mount the hdd to save my files`?

Comment: Have you tried to boot with OBCD?

Comment: @bonchance90 at least you can try, TrueCrypt have an option to mount the whole device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BootMgr is missing, usual fixes don't work](http://superuser.com/questions/358651/bootmgr-is-missing-usual-fixes-dont-work)

Answer (score -1):

This was a one line fix for me:

**bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s c:**

It took 2 days for researching via a phone, backing up the drive, then permanently decrypting via Truecrypt boot loader, but it did work.

To execute, get to the Windows recovery environment using Startup Repair or a Win 7 cd, mount truecrypt using UBCD4Win (or perhaps from a flash drive may be easier) and run that command above on the letter drive you've selected to mount on.

Props to OP for the command: https://superuser.com/a/937292/551538

In terms of your files, this method above should allow you to backup your files as well, with the data being decrypted on the fly. Note you have to go into select a restore point from within the Win 7 environment, then click add driver and that will allow you to open up an explorer-like tool to copy. Another recovery environment where you can run Truecrypt would also do the trick for backing up.